# creating multiple lists from a master nested list

Tags: python, database, custom-lists

I have a nested list that I got from data that will be broken into sections to be uploaded to a database but have to be separate entries.

My nested list:

```
Master_List = [ a, [1,2,3], [1,2], d]
```

But I need to make it into six separate lists such as this:

```
list1 = [a, 1, 1, d] 
list2 = [a, 1, 2, d]
list3 = [a, 2, 1, d]
list4 = [a, 2, 2, d]
etc.
```

I've tried iterating through the lists through the values of the list, but I'm confused since not all the master list indices will have more than one value. How do can I build these separate lists to be used?

When I tried just iterating through the lists and creating separate lists it became a convoluted mess.

Edit: Coldspeed's solution is exactly what I needed. Now I just use the dictionary to access the list I want.

Comment: Well, what've you tried thus far?

Comment: I've tried iterating through the lists through the values of the list, but I'm confused since not all the master list indices will have more than one value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be using `itertools.product`.

```
from itertools import product
out = {'list{}'.format(i) : list(l) for i, l in enumerate(product(*Master_List), 1)}

print(out)
{'list1': ['a', 1, 1, 'd'],
 'list2': ['a', 1, 2, 'd'],
 'list3': ['a', 2, 1, 'd'],
 'list4': ['a', 2, 2, 'd'],
 'list5': ['a', 3, 1, 'd'],
 'list6': ['a', 3, 2, 'd']}
```

Unfortunately, you cannot create a variable number of variables without the use of a dictionary. If you want to access `listX`, you'll access the `out` dictionary, like this:

```
out['listX']
```

Comment: I've never heard of itertools, I looked at the documentation, the solution works exactly how I need it, example to access the first index of list 1 is now written as out['list1'][0]. 

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner would be:

```
lists = sum([[[Master_List[0], i, j, Master_List[3]] for i in Master_List[1]] for j in Master_List[2]], [])
```

Comment: I was looking to create multiple, separate lists, but I can now just iterate through the new list  'lists' now. Thank you.